# pass line breaks in text area input

Tags: php, html

I have a textarea input on a form for users to submit their snail mail address.
This is the code I have `<textarea name="Mail" rows="4" ></textarea>`
I would like for the line breaks in the text area to be passed in the POST data so that the address will appear properly in the code `echo $_POST['Mail'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
 print nl2br($_POST['Mail']);
```

Comment: Also, deter XSS with: `print nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['Mail']));`  To explain the nl2br() further, the problem wasn't that newlines weren't being passed from the input, it's that newlines don't display as newlines in HTML in output.

Comment: @Frank Farmer: i have kept my answer limited to the question, of course there are a host of considerations when it comes to security not just xss. thanks anyways